# Using C's free is keeping data in a local string

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm currently working my way through [buildyourownlisp.com](http://buildyourownlisp.com) and have run into an issue when I'm parsing floats.  Here's the relevant function:

```
lval* lval_read_float(mpc_ast_t* ast) {
    errno = 0;
    char* float_string;
    float_string = (char *) malloc(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < ast->children_num; i++) {
        char* child = ast->children[i]->contents;
        float_string = realloc(float_string, sizeof(float_string) + sizeof(child));
        strcat(float_string, child);
    }
    printf("Assembled string: %s\n", float_string);
    float x = strtod(float_string, NULL);
    free(float_string);
    printf("Float: %f\n", x);
    return errno != ERANGE ? lval_float(x) : lval_err("Invalid float");
}
```

This works basically as intended when I don't free() the float_string.  When I add the call to free(float_string), data is being stored in the local variable between lval_read_float() calls.  For example, if I run:

```
lispy> + 2.5 2.5
```

I will receive the output:

```
Assembled string: 2.5
Float: 2.500000
Assembled string: 2.52.5
Float: 2.520000
```

While I haven't programmed much in C, I find this behavior baffling on many levels.  What am I missing when it comes to memory allocation and free?

Comment: `sizeof() != strlen()`

Comment: If you look at the size you're generating for the size of your `realloc()` I believe the results will surprise you. `sizeof(char *)` is the size of a pointer on your system, and since both `float_string` and `child` are `char *`s, you're getting the fixed size of two pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You apply `sizeof()` operator to pointers, which will give you the size of POINTER, not the string. Use `strlen()` instead and it will work fine.

Replace:

```
float_string = realloc(float_string, sizeof(float_string) + sizeof(child));
```

with:

```
float_string = realloc(float_string, strlen(float_string) + strlen(child) + 1);
```

The extra "+1" at the end is for the terminating '\0' character, which is not counted by `strlen()`.

As @mah noted below, you also need to initialize the memory before first use for your loop to work correctly. That's why below that:

```
float_string = (char *) malloc(1);
```

you should add:

```
*float_string = '\0';
```

Comment: Note that `strlen(float_string)`, the first time through the loop, will take the length of uninitialized memory.

Comment: I swapped out the sizeof() for strlen() but that didn't change the behavior.  It was initializing the empty float_string that fixed things and I'm trying to figure out why this would be.  As for retaining local variable information between loops:  Is it that if it's allocating the same memory block, the first strcat() in the loop would read through the null terminator from the previous float_string?

Comment: A note on your `realloc()` line: I don't believe you need the +1 inside.  The `realloc()` is based on the length of the `float_string` (which is now properly initialized to 1) so there is a single +1 overall instead of the +1 that will be added every time it goes through the loop in your function.

Comment: @bjornsen: No. Those who do not understand `strlen()` are doomed to repeat it. (As Schlemiel the painter remarked.)